# Ocaml: build list for Ast type in recursive function

Tags: parsing, ocaml, recursive-descent

I have a handwritten LL1 parser. My AST is not as simplified as it could be. The portion for statements looks like this:

```
type stmt_opt = StmtExpression of assignment | OptNil
[@@deriving show]
(*stmt_list -> stmt stmt_list | ε *)
type stmtlist =
    | StmtList of stmt * stmtlist
    | StmtlistNil 
[@@deriving show]

and stmt = 
| Assignment of assignment
| Return of stmt_opt 
| Parentheses of stmtlist
| If of assignment * stmt
| For of assignment * assignment * assignment * stmt
| While of assignment * stmt
(*“lparen” formals_opt “rparen” “LBRACE” vdecl_list stmt_list “RBRACE”*)
[@@deriving show]
```

As you can see, I'm still holding onto a lot of unnecessary information. I'd like to build my statement ast like this:

```
type stmt =
    Block of stmt list
  | Expr of expr
  | Return of expr
  | If of expr * stmt * stmt
  | For of expr * expr * expr * stmt
  | While of expr * stmt
```

I'm a little lost as to do this because I really built my LL1 parser by the books (which I believe don't anticipate very long grammars): every nonterminal has a parse method and every parse method returns a tokenlist and an ast.

I think, in order to build a Block type like in my goal statement AST, I need to build a list of statements inside my recursive parseStmt method. I have reduced my parser code to only the parser methods that call parseStmtList and the specific instances where they call parseStmtList

```
(*stmt_list = stmt stmt_list | epsilon*)
let rec parseStmtList tokenlist lst = 
    match tokenlist.head with 
    | Lexer.RightBrace -> (tokenlist, Ast.StmtlistNil )
    | _ -> let (tokenlist_stmt, stmt) = parseStmt tokenlist in 
          let new_lst = lst::stmt in
          let (tokenlist_stmt_list, stmt_list) = tokenlist_stmt new_lst |> parseStmtList in
          (tokenlist_stmt_list, Ast.Block(stmt_lst))

(*stmt -> assignment SEMI 
|  RETURN stmt_opt SEMI
|  LBRACE stmt_list RBRACE 
|  IF LPAREN assignment RPAREN stmt 
|  FOR LPAREN assignment SEMI assignment SEMI assignment RPAREN stmt  
|  WHILE LPAREN assignment RPAREN stmt
*)

and parseStmt tokenlist = 
   begin
   match tokenlist.head with 
   | Lexer.ID identifier -> let (tokenlist_assignment, assignment) = parseAssignment tokenlist in
                begin
                match tokenlist_assignment.head with
                | Lexer.Semicolon -> (next tokenlist_assignment, Ast.Assignment(assignment))
                | _-> let err_msg = __LOC__ ^ "Syntax Error semicolon expected but received" ^ show_token_list tokenlist in
                     raise (Syntax_error err_msg) 
                end
         | Lexer.LeftBrace -> let tokenlist_leftbrace = next tokenlist in 
                        let (tokenlist_expr, expr) = parseStmtList tokenlist_leftbrace [] in
                        begin
                        match tokenlist_expr.head with
                        | Lexer.RightBrace -> (next tokenlist_expr, Ast.Parentheses(expr))
                        | _-> let err_msg = __LOC__ ^ "Syntax Error right brace expected but received" ^ show_token_list tokenlist in
                              raise (Syntax_error err_msg)
                        end
   | _-> let err_msg = __LOC__ ^ "Syntax Error left brace expected but received" ^ show_token_list tokenlist in
                    raise (Syntax_error err_msg)
    end
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a -> token_list * Ast.stmtlist
       but an expression was expected of type 'b * 'c
```

for the line `let (tokenlist_stmt_list, stmt_list) = tokenlist_stmt new_lst |> parseStmtList in` in `parseStmtList`

Comment: Could you (1) add some context for where the type error is coming from and (2) try to give a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example)? The current wall of code makes it hard to understand what is going on, without cloning your code locally, setting up dependencies etc. Afaict, you've got an ordinary type error, which isn't really connected to parsing/recursive-descent.

Comment: I haven't really look at your code yet (as theindigamer said, you should really try to give a proper MCVE), but if you take your working version of `parseStmtList` that uses `stmtlist` and just replace every occurrence of `StmtList (foo, bar)` with `foo :: bar` and every occurrence of `StmtListNil` with `[]`, that's all you should need to change to get a working version using `stmt list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tokenlist_stmt new_lst |> parseStmtList
```

Here you're applying `tokenlist_stmt` to the argument `new_lst` and then applying `parseStmtList` to the result. But `tokenlist_stmt` isn't actually a function, so this a type error.

Presumably your intention was to call `parseStmtList` with `tokenlist_stmt` and `new_lst` as its two argument. The syntax for that is simply:

```
parseStmtList tokenlist_stmt new_lst
```

Further `lst::stmt` is also a type error for two reasons:

1. `::` takes the list as its right operand, not the left, so it should be `stmt::lst`
2. `lst` isn't actually a list, it's an `Ast.Block` because that's what `parseStmtList` returns.

Once you've fixed all that, you'll notice that the list will be the wrong way around (presumably that's why you tried `lst::stmt` in the first place, but you can't append to the end of a list like that). That's a common problem when building a list with an accumulator. The solution is to either reverse the list once you're done building it or to not use an accumulator in the first place.

---

One thing that's important to point out is that all of those issues would have applied when using `Ast.stmtlist` as well. That is, if your code looked like this:

```
let new_lst = Ast.StmtList(lst, stmt) in
let (tokenlist_stmt_list, stmt_list) = tokenlist_stmt new_lst |> parseStmtList in
(tokenlist_stmt_list, Ast.Block(stmt_lst))
```

Then you'd get the exact same errors. This makes me think, that you've changed way more of the code than you would have needed to. Since your old code presumably worked, I'll assume that it looked something like this:

```
let rec parseStmtList tokenlist = 
    match tokenlist.head with 
    | Lexer.RightBrace -> (tokenlist, Ast.StmtlistNil )
    | _ -> let (tokenlist_stmt, stmt) = parseStmt tokenlist in 
          let (tokenlist_stmt_list, stmt_list) = parseStmtList tokenlist_stmt in
          (tokenlist_stmt_list, Ast.StmtList (stmt, stmt_lst))
```

and then in `parseStmt` you had:

```
let (tokenlist_stmtlist, stmtlist) = parseStmtList tokenlist_leftbrace in
begin
  match tokenlist_expr.head with
  | Lexer.RightBrace -> (next tokenlist_stmtlist, Ast.Block(stmtlist))
```

Now after removing `Ast.stmtlist`, all you need to change are the parts where you actually used its constructors and replace those parts with the list constructors (`::` and `[]`). So the code in `parseStmt` would stay completely unchanged and the only changes in `parseStmtList` should be to replace the line

```
| Lexer.RightBrace -> (tokenlist, Ast.StmtlistNil )
```

with

```
| Lexer.RightBrace -> (tokenlist, [] )
```

and the line

```
(tokenlist_stmt_list, Ast.StmtList (stmt, stmt_lst))
```

with

```
(tokenlist_stmt_list, stmt :: stmt_lst)
```

If your old code looked differently than what I came up with above, you might have to change different lines, but the idea remains the same: Replace `Ast.StmtList` with `::` and `Ast.StmtListNil` with `[]`.

And that's it. That's all the change that's necessary. You were way overcomplicating it.

Comment: this is a great catch! however, now the same line gives `This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list`

Comment: @Matt Ah, `lst::stmt` is the wrong way around. The left operand to `::` is the new element and the right operand the list, so it should be `stmt :: list`.

Comment: a final question - Ast.Block(stmt_lst) returns `This expression has type Ast.stmt
       but an expression was expected of type Ast.stmt list`. I changed my code around to use `Ast.Block(lst, stmt))` but got `This expression has type 'a * 'b
       but an expression was expected of type Ast.stmt list`

Comment: @Matt I want to refer you back to my first comment on your question: All you had to change from your original code was to replace `StmtList` with `::` and `StmtListNil` with `[]`. I believe your problem in this instance is that `parseStmtList` returns a block, but you treat it like it returns a list (which it actually should), but instead of fixing your problems one-by-one, I recommend that you simply go back to your original code and just change the two things I mentioned.

Comment: I minimized my code so hopefully its more readable. I don't understand why replacing StmtList(foo, bar) with foo::bar would work - I want to get rid of stmtlist type in my ast completely and create a Ast.Block ( type stmt) - if parseStmtList returns (foo :: bar) how will the AST its type?

Comment: @Matt Previously your `parseStmtList` returned a `stmtlist` right? Not an `Ast.Block`. So why shouldn't it return a `stmt list` now? In what way would that be a problem if it returning a `stmtlist` wasn't a problem before?

Comment: Or let me approach this differently: Let's say that instead of removing `stmtlist`, you simply changed its name to `mylist` and then you changed the names of the constructors to `MyCons` and `MyNil` respectively. Then all you would have to do to `parseStmtList` would be to change `StmtList` to `MyCons` and `StmtLstNil` to `MyNil`, right? And that's all you'd have to change in your code. So now all you need to realize is that all you did here is to "rename" `stmtlist` to `stmt list`, `StmtList` to `::` and `StmtListNil` to `[]`, except that the `smt list` type was already built in.

Comment: No my parseStmtList returned `Ast.StmtList` of `stmt * stmtlist` (not `stmt list`) this is in the portion of ast file i put in beginning of post

Comment: @Matt I know that it returned `Ast.stmtlist`. I'm saying that `Ast.stmtlist` is isomorphic to `stmt list`, so in your new code it should return that, not `Ast.stmt`. Because why would it suddenly return a statement when it didn't before?

Comment: @Matt I've amended my answer to expand on my comments. Hopefully this makes things clearer.